# Change a vps' welcome message

Tags: command-line, bashrc, vps

When I log into my sudo user on an Ubuntu vps, this message appears:

> There is a Quick installer available in /usr/sbin named
>   quickinstaller.sh. It will give you the option of installing a LAMP

Ubuntu nooby here, but I think the .bashrc file for each user is responsible for what's run during a login. So is the code that triggers this message in .bashrc ?

How can I change this message? Could I even run a command-line program on startup to give diagnostic information maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you wanna do, is changing the motd (Message of the day).

Have a look at [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/update-motd.5.html) to get some ideas of how the overall motd works under Ubuntu.
[This one](http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/) can also give you some ideas.